# What is relationship between fabric-sdk-java and shim for java

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

What is relationship between [fabric-sdk-java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) and [shim for java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/core/chaincode/shim/java)?

[shim for java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/core/chaincode/shim/java) located in the fabric source code .Why fabric written by golang have java code? fabric-sdk-java is independent project . It seems they could visit grpc server (like peer and orderer) , so What is the relationship between them ?

Answer (score 1):

The SDKs are independent of the chaincode. You can use the Node.js SDK with golang chaincode, with Java chaincode or Node.js chaincode. Does not need to be consistent.

The reason that the (java) shim is in the golang codebase is just to have a place to put it where, as has been noted, we can share the .proto files that define the gRPC interfaces. With the advent of the independent repos for the [Java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java) and [Node.js](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node) chaincode shims, a refactoring will soon be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The Hyperledger Fabric that is implementation of [blockchain technology](https://openblockchain.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/JAVAChaincode/) offer number of SDKs for different programming languages, the available are in Node.js and Java SDK. 
        Fabric written by [golang](http://fabric-chaintool.readthedocs.io/en/latest/platforms/golang/#golang-chaincode-platform) are in java because Fabric is available in Java and NodeJs and Java is accepted by more developers, but doesnt matter it just be anything among them.
       Yes they communicating with Blockchain using gRPC. Earlier it was supporting REST APIs but seem like they stopped support for it in newly released V1.0 version.

If we are twist things a bit, and have independent repositories for each language's shim it would make thing a bit cleaner  and it would
significantly reduce the size of chaincode deploys.

The one issue we ran up against is how to keep them aligned. We could simply copy. The .proto from fabric and check it into the shim repos. Awkward but
effective.

So, what we have is:

fabric
fabric-go-shim
fabric-java-shim
...

we would maintain the .proto in fabric and copy to the fabric--shim
repo as needed, but it would not be edited. We'd need to document this
carefully.
Each repo could manage its own dependency management publishing (e.g.
javascript to npm, java to maven, etc).